# How do you tell if zmq.Socket.send_multipart fails with Dealer/Router socket pair?

Tags: python, zeromq, python-asyncio

When sending data in a non-blocking fashion via [zmq.Socket.send_multipart](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.send_multipart), how does one tell if the operation fails? For example, in the [aiozmq library](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiozmq/blob/7ab57b78a532cee4b9cd93eadf25d7b51952e82c/aiozmq/core.py#L678), which is what I'm trying to debug:

```
self._zmq_sock.send_multipart(data, zmq.DONTWAIT)
```

My scenario is that a server sends data via zmq.Socket.send_multipart, but the client never receives it, so I'm wondering if the sending of the data simply fails througout.

Comment: Depends on the type of socket.  For example, PUB sockets will silently drop when there are no peers, DEALER will queue until a peer arrives and ROUTER will drop by default (but a socket option allows obtaining an error code if the peer has disconnected).  What type of socket are you using?

Comment: @AndréCaron The server uses zmq.ROUTER, while the client uses zmq.DEALER.

Comment: @AndréCaron Is it easier to detect an error if DONTWAIT isn't used, i.e. `self._zmq_sock.send_multipart(data)`?

Comment: I don't know, but I would think not: that flag only tells ZMQ not to block when the queue is full.  For router sockets, you may be interested in using the [ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-setsockopt#toc24) socket option.  That will tell you if the message would be dropped when the peer has disconnected.  *However*, it will *not* tell you if the message is lost for other reasons (e.g. network conditions).  Have you looked into using a ZMQ monitor?

Comment: @AndréCaron I'm not familiar with ZMQ monitors, no. I'm really only a client of the aiozmq library, but I need it to work.

Comment: @AndréCaron ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY will only matter if you specify the identity of the client you're sending to, right? Do you have an example of how to propagate this identity?

Comment: @AndréCaron Nevermind, I think I can see that the client ID is taken care of by the library.

Comment: you have to specify the peer's identity when sending or the router wouldn't know where to route to :-)

Comment: @AndréCaron I think I read somewhere that the Router wouldn't cause EHOSTUNREACH unless the client's ID was specified.